# How can I create an SQL table name with spaces and wildcard characters in a MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, wildcard

I am looking for a way to store a value with spaces and wildcard characters in a MySQL table. How can this be done? I have tried using `mysql_real_escape_string` but for some reason it still won't create a table with the wildcard characters. I've been doing some research and I know it's not that complicated but can't find what I'm looking for.

EXAMPLE OF INSERTION:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $_COOKIE['username'] . "_" . mysql_real_escape_string($wildcard_name) . "
(
example int,
example2 varchar(999),
example3 varchar(999),
example4 varchar(999)
)";
mysql_query($sql,$con);
```

Trying to add slashes:

```
$con = mysql_connect("server","user","pass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  $scrapbook_name = $_POST["scrapbook_name"];
$scrapbook_name = mysql_real_escape_string($scrapbook_name);
$scrapbook_name = addcslashes($scrapbook_name, '%_');
// Create table
mysql_select_db("user_scrapbooks", $con);
$sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $_COOKIE['user'] . "_" . $scrapbook_name . "
(
id int,
name varchar(999),
description varchar(999),
link varchar(999)
)";
mysql_query($sql,$con);
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the insertion? Spaces shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Vache added to question above.

Comment: Are you sure that you actually want to create a new table an not insert into it? (Sorry if it sounds like a stupid question, but I don't know where you're going from your example...)

Comment: Sorry, that's a good question. This is only part of the code, but the point of my question I'm trying to ask is how to use a wildcard "string" and use it with MySQL. I do insert it later in the code aswell.

Comment: It matters because the characters you can use for a table name and for stored data are very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the 'addcslashes' function to escape the wildcard characters.

```
$x = mysql_real_escape_string($x);
$x = addcslashes($x, '%_');
```

[addcslashes doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php)

Comment: Would this work with a url though? Also would this fix any possible issues with an SQL injection attack?

Comment: The function is usable on any string, shouldn't be a problem with URLs. Basically the second parameter to the function is the character you want to manually escape. It could help with preventing SQL injection since your adding the escapes. Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried to add slashes (see above) but it still won't create the table, or the rows of data (ignoring) for that matter. Why is this? The scrapbook_name represents the wildcard string (hello moto). Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think the question doesn't match up with what your actually trying to do. To insert a string into table, you would be fine with using mysql_real_escape_string and addcslashes. However from looking at the code, your actually trying to create a table (not insert data into one). Your going to have to strip (not escape) those characters in order to create a table name.

Comment: How would I strip those characters?

Answer (score 0):

You should create table using ` quote.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @mysql_select_db('mydb') or die(DBCUSTOMERROR);
$mydata = ' * * ? % ';
$query = "INSERT INTO `mydb`.`mytable` ( `MyVarCharField`) VALUES  ('". $mydata.  "' );";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $_COOKIE['username'] . "_" 
       . mysql_real_escape_string($wildcard_name) . "
```

It appears that you're not trying to store a *value* with special characters, you're actually trying to create a *table identifier* with special characters.

You can delimit identifiers in SQL, so you can permit special characters, spaces, international characters, SQL keyword, etc.  In MySQL, the identifier delimiter is a back-tick.  In ANSI SQL (or MySQL with `SET SQL_MODE='ANSI'`) the identifier delimiter is a double-quote.

So you could create a table name that would normally be invalid if you delimit it any time you use it:

```
CREATE TABLE `SELECT - ORDER` ( ... );
INSERT INTO `SELECT - ORDER` VALUES ( ... );
SELECT ... FROM `SELECT - ORDER`;
```

However, `mysql_real_escape_string()` is not the right function to use for preparing strings to be used safely as an identifier.  That function is for string values, to make them safe within single-quoted strings.  **`mysql_real_escape_string()` doesn't escape back-tick.**  So you could have a problem if your table name contains a back-tick, even if you try to escape it and delimit it:

```
$user_name = "foo` bar";
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) ...
```

Results in an invalid SQL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` bar` ...
```

You should really filter the cookie contents, stripping out invalid characters.  Then you have more assurance that it won't cause a problem.

```
$user_name = preg_replace('/`/u', '', $_COOKIE['username']);
$table_name = "{$username}_{$wildcard_name}";
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `{$table_name}` ...";
```

You don't need to escape single-quotes or double-quotes or LIKE-wildcards for a table name.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong on this (please correct me if I am), but couldn't you use [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) for this?